# Almost unreadable input assistant text using the official stylesheet "ReverseColor"

Tags: front-end, color

When I use Mathematica's ReverseColor the input assistant is shown in almost the same color as the block's background. (Grey tones). See picture below:
[image]

Can this really be true? Or is it a bug on my version?

If it's not a bug, I will send Mathematica feedback to change it.

Comment: This is a known, terrible design choice on WRI's part. It can be customized away, but you should still report it.